# Update props value in vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

How to update props value by method in vue?
So I have props width with default value is 20

```
<div :style="{ width: width+ 'px'}">
```

```
props: {
  width: {
    type: [String, Number],
    default: '20px'
  },
}
```

and then it will rendered the component to width=20px. Can I change the props value by using javascript? Example it might look like this(?)

```
myEventHandler(e) {
  if(window.innerWidth < 768 && this.width === '20')
  this.width = '' // I want to revert the value to empty like it never used this props before. But I get vue warn that the prop being mutated
},
```

Any help would be very helful, thanks!

Comment: You are not supposed to update the prop value from the child component. You can send an event to the parent so that it updates the value given in the props, or you can use an intermediary value from the child's data, that you update when the prop changes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As stated in the VueJs documentation: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-props.html#One-Way-Data-Flow

> This means you should not attempt to mutate a prop inside a child
> component. If you do, Vue will warn you in the console.

If you really really need to mutate the props, you can try something like:
In the child component:

```
props: {
  width: {
    type: [String, Number],
    default: '20px'
  }
},
computed: {
  computedWidth: {
    get(){
      return this.width
    },
    set(newValue) {
      this.$emit('widthChanged', newValue)
    }
  }
}
```

In the parent component:

```
<child-component
  :width="width"
  @widthChanged="someFunctionWhoMutateYourVar"
>
```

This should do the work